# How to represent a x value in pow() function

Tags: python

I am trying to represent a function in **python**.

The function is:

```
(x^2)-(y+1)^2
```

The **pow()** function can't accept string as an argument.

I have been tried to represent it in this way:

```
math.pow(x,2)- math.pow(y+1,2)
```

But an error appeared:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: are `x` and `y` of type `str` ?

Comment: No, X and Y are real numbers (float)

Comment: @Nasser_Omar According to the error message, at least one is indeed a string. A string that represents a number is still a string. See my answer for the solution

Comment: @DeepSpace Big thanks for you. Your answer is useful. It solved the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `x` and `y` to `int` (or `float` if applicable).

```
math.pow(int(x), 2) - math.pow(int(y) + 1, 2)
```